# Use Email Templates instead of Automated Messages

Tags: civimail, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

Need your help...I'm trying to send a custom email automatically when a contact is created via the 'Sign Up' page...I'm using a profile in the page with 'Add To Email Group' enabled and I've also enabled the Double Opt-In to send an email back to the newly signed up contact....I see that the message comes from the Automated Messages section...I want to use an email template instead so that I can include the Contact information in the email...Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: what CMS? Drupal has more options for this sort of task

Comment: Its on Wordpress CMS

Comment: my lips are sealed then ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the CiviRules Extension?

Comment: Yup..This is what I was looking for:)....Thanks Carl:)